# stack around the variable "pd" was corrupted

Tags: c++

Программа должна считывать из файла элементы матрицы, но в конце выдаёт ошибку stack around the variable pd was corrupted. Где ошибка?

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;
#pragma once

int main()
{
    setlocale(0, "");
    FILE *fin, *fout;
    errno_t err;
    char pd;
    int size;
    err=fopen_s(&fin,"a.txt","r");
    if (err != 0)
        exit(1);
    fread((void*)&pd, 1, 1, fin);
    size = (int)pd - 48;
    cout <<"Размер массива равен "<<size<<endl;

    int **arr = new int*[size];
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        arr[i] = new int[size];
    }
    fseek(fin, 0L, SEEK_SET);
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
            int counter = 0;
            fread((void*)&pd, 2, 1, fin);
            if (pd == ' '||pd=='\0')
                continue;
            arr[i][j] = (int)pd - 48;           
        }
    }
    fclose(fin);
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
            cout << arr[i][j] << " ";
            ++count;
            if (count % size==0)
                cout << endl;

        }
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Как минимум если

```
char pd;
```

т.е. 1 байт, то куда вы читаете

```
fread((void*)&pd, 2, 1, fin);
```

два байта?...

А вообще - совершенно непонятна структура вашего файла...

Comment: Если читается 1 байт, то выдаёт некорректные значения. Оно записывает -842150451

Comment: Извините, но это уже ваши проблемы - вы ни слова не написали, что там на самом деле в вашем файле. Есть у меня большое подозрение, что вы вообще делаете ерунду...

Comment: В начале написана суть программы

Comment: Не вынуждайте меня прибегать к непечатным выражениям. Если вы считаете, что это - описание формата файла, то, уверяю вас, вы очень сильно заблуждаетесь. Не ленитесь - помощь нужна вам. Еще раз - мне кажется, что вы делаете что-то неверное - например, если первым **символом** у вас записан размер - зачем вы пытаетесь читать его повторно, как элемент матрицы?..